# How to hide side nav bar using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, web-applications, css-transitions

Hi I want my navbar to be automatically hidden when I move the mouse.There is an example i want to use https://codepen.io/JFarrow/pen/fFrpg. I have read some document online, but I still can not figure out how.. Here is my  code:

```css
li .glyphicon {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

/* Highlighting rules for nav menu items */
li.link-active a,
li.link-active a:hover,
li.link-active a:focus {
    background-color: #4189C7;
    color: white;
}

/* Keep the nav menu independent of scrolling and on top of other items */
.main-nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    /* On small screens, convert the nav menu to a vertical sidebar */
    .main-nav {
        height: 100%;
        width: calc(25% - 20px);
    }
    .navbar {
        border-radius: 0px;
        border-width: 0px;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid #444;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    .navbar ul {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar li {
        float: none;
        font-size: 15px;
        margin: 6px;
    }
    .navbar li a {
        padding: 10px 16px;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }
    .navbar a {
        /* If a menu item's text is too long, truncate it */
        width: 100%;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class='main-nav'>
    <div class='navbar navbar-inverse'>
        <div class='navbar-header'>
            <a class='navbar-brand' [routerLink]="['/home']">Navbar</a>
            <button type='button' class='navbar-toggle' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='.navbar-collapse'>
                <span  (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                <span class='icon-bar'></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class='clearfix'></div>
        <div class='navbar-collapse collapse' >
                <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
                    <li [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']">
                        <a [routerLink]="['/home']">
                            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-home'></span> Home
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']">
                        <a [routerLink]="['/login']">
                            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-log-in'></span> Log In
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']">
                        <a [routerLink]="['/margin']">
                            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-list'></span> Report
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']">
                        <a [routerLink]="['/smart-table']">
                            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-list'></span> Smart table
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I am not sure where should I add the code. There are codes online about adding a js function, or using some buid in bootstrap function, just not work for me....

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply achieve this effect with only some lines of CSS.

First add a wrapper for your navigation item labels, i.e. `.nav-label`:

```
...
<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-home'></span> <span class="nav-label">Home</span>
...
```

Now by using a different [`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width) for the `.main-nav` on hover, apply a [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) effect and hide the `.nav-labels` by default:

```
.main-nav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  transition: all .1s linear;
}
.main-nav:hover {
  width: calc(25% - 20px)
}
.main-nav:hover .nav-label {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Here is the working example with your code (view it in fullscreen mode to see the sidebar action):

```css
li .glyphicon {
  margin-right: 10px;
}


/* Highlighting rules for nav menu items */

li.link-active a,
li.link-active a:hover,
li.link-active a:focus {
  background-color: #4189C7;
  color: white;
}


/* Keep the nav menu independent of scrolling and on top of other items */

.main-nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.main-nav .navbar-nav>li {
  float: none;
}

.nav-label {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 2em;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  /* On small screens, convert the nav menu to a vertical sidebar */
  .main-nav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
    transition: all .1s linear;
  }
  .main-nav:hover {
    width: calc(25% - 20px)
  }
  .main-nav:hover .nav-label {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .navbar {
    border-radius: 0px;
    border-width: 0px;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .navbar-collapse {
    border-top: 1px solid #444;
    padding: 0px;
  }
  .navbar li {
    display: block;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 6px;
  }
  .navbar li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 16px;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
  .navbar a {
    /* If a menu item's text is too long, truncate it */
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class='main-nav'>
  <div class='navbar navbar-inverse'>
    <div class='navbar-header'>
      <a class='navbar-brand' [routerLink]="['/home']">Navbar</a>
      <button type='button' class='navbar-toggle' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='.navbar-collapse'>
          <span  (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class='icon-bar'></span>
          <span class='icon-bar'></span>
          <span class='icon-bar'></span>
          <span class='icon-bar'></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class='clearfix'></div>
    <div class='navbar-collapse collapse'>
      <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
        <li [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']">
          <a [routerLink]="['/home']">
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-home'></span> <span class="nav-label">Home</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']">
          <a [routerLink]="['/login']">
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-log-in'></span> <span class="nav-label">Log In</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']">
          <a [routerLink]="['/margin']">
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-list'></span> <span class="nav-label">Report</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']">
          <a [routerLink]="['/smart-table']">
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-list'></span> <span class="nav-label">Smart table</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to look for mouseenter / mouseleave events and add some class to your navigation.

Example:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.main-nav', function() {
  $(this).addClass('expanded'); //Add Class for full nav
});

$(document).on('mouseleave', '.main-nav', function() {
  $(this).removeClass('expanded');  //Return to small nav
});
```

This is solution with Javascript or you can have with simple CSS solution just changing the display/width of one part of navigation.